# timer is reset when the page is refreshed javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, nan

I'm trying to make a quiz timer. but, when the page is refreshed the timer is reset, How to solve this?

```html
<html><h1>Js Timer</h1>
<div style="font-weight: bold;" id="quiz-time-left"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total_seconds = 60*2
    var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
    var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
    function CheckTime() {
        document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML
        ='Time Left: ' + c_minutes + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds' ;
        if (total_seconds <=0) {
            setTimeout('document.quiz.submit()',1);
        }else{
            total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
            c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
            c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
            
            setTimeout("CheckTime()",1000);
        }
    }
    setTimeout("CheckTime()",1000);
</script>
<form method="post" name="quiz" action="http://10.11.3.102/sisfo/pegawai/timer"></form>
```

Comment: JavaScript is client side programming language means it is accessible by any user. What you need is put your timer in server side or in database. You can just store start time so that in each refresh you will get remaining time only.

Answer (score 0):

If server-side timer not required, you can use localstorage for storing time remaining in timer and use it when page is refreshed.

```
<html><h1>Js Timer</h1>
<div style="font-weight: bold;" id="quiz-time-left"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Checking localstorage to check if timer is remaning
var total_seconds =window.localStorage.getItem('total_seconds');

    total_seconds = (total_seconds!=null && total_seconds>0)?total_seconds:60*2;
    var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
    var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
    function CheckTime() {
        document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML
        ='Time Left: ' + c_minutes + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds' ;
        if (total_seconds <=0) {
            setTimeout('document.quiz.submit()',1);

    //Clearing localstorage when reseting timer
    window.localStorage.clear('total_seconds');
        }else{
            total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
            c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
            c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);

            setTimeout("CheckTime()",1000);
        }

    //Updating timer data in localstorage
    window.localStorage.setItem('total_seconds', total_seconds);
    }
    setTimeout("CheckTime()",1000);
</script>
<form method="post" name="quiz" action="http://10.11.3.102/sisfo/pegawai/timer"></form>
```

Comment: Dear, User can change `local storage`.

Comment: @RishiRaut As per the Problem here, the user just want to preserve timer when the page is refreshed. 
If the basic motto is to preserve timer even if page is refreshed, then localstorage will serve the purpose. If the requirement is to build a strict timer then server-side timer validation will be required.

Comment: @lalugde If the answer works for you mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that everytime a page is reloaded, the entire code is compiled/ executed from the top downwards. Once it reaches the initialization part :

> var total_seconds = 60*2
>
> var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
>
> var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);

The total_seconds is reset to 60*2

If you don't want the time to be reset, you will have to use a storage memory that doesn't reload with the page. That will be sessions.

***You could use localStorage but i wouldn't recommend it as it keeps the variable even when the browser is closed.***

The sessionStorage information can be found on w3schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp).

> // Store
>
> sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
>
> // Retrieve
>
> document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");

This data is reset when you close a browser tab or close the browser.